# Merging 2 subgoals with common unknown variable in Isabelle proof

Tags: isabelle

Im currently trying to prove a lemma in Isabelle and I'm left with 2 subgoals, which both have the same unknown variable **?Q11**. 
Is it possible to merge the two subgoals into one by "transitivity"?
That is by replacing **?Q11** in the second subgoal by the set in which **?Q11** is contained in the first subgoal.

```
goal (2 subgoals):
 1. ⋀s. ?Q11 s ⊆ {s. s⦇msg_sender := address_this s, address_this := add2 s⦈ ∈ {s. s⦇g := 2⦈ ∈ {t. g t = 2}}}
 2. {s. g s = 0} ⊆ {s. s⦇msg_sender := address_this s, address_this := add1 s⦈ ∈ {sa. sa⦇g := 1⦈ ∈ ?Q11 s}}
```

The goal I would like to obtain would be something like

```
 1. {s. g s = 0} ⊆ {s. s⦇msg_sender := address_this s, address_this := add1 s⦈ ∈ {sa. sa⦇g := 1⦈ ∈ {s. s⦇msg_sender := address_this s, address_this := add2 s⦈ ∈ {s. s⦇g := 2⦈ ∈ {t. g t = 2}}}}}
```

which is proven directly by simp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
apply (rule order.refl)
```

which solves the first goal using reflexivity of the subset relation. This instatiates ?Q11 accordingly.

Of course this does not really "merge subgoals", but it achieves the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes, it does exactly what I was looking for, shouldn't really have used the term "merge".